# momentjs date parsing default timezone without moment-timezone

Tags: datetime, momentjs

`momentjs` clearly has a concept of a "default" timezone without involving `moment-timezone` or `moment.tz`.

my dev machine is in CET and when I write this it's currently DST (+0200).

example:

```
var moment = require('moment');  // no moment-timezone
```

The following time (without timezone suffix) is **just before** the DST switch CET.

```
moment('2015-03-29T02:00:00').format() // '2015-03-29T01:00:00+01:00'
```

And this time is **just after** the DST switch CET.

```
moment('2015-03-29T03:00:00').format() // '2015-03-29T03:00:00+02:00'
```

Moment has clearly interpreted my input using some hidden knowledge that I want CET and the DST rules for CET.

How can I affect this?

If I move my dev-machine to New York, can I convince moment to continue using the CET rules?

(and moment-timezone is probably not the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying the time zone, no, it will create the date based on the current time zone on your machine. From the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

> Unless you specify a timezone offset, parsing a string will create a
>   date in the current timezone.
>
> ```
> moment("2010-10-20 4:30",       "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");   // parsed as 4:30 local time
> moment("2010-10-20 4:30 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"); // parsed as 4:30 UTC
> ```

Comment: Problem is that if I set a time zone, the DST logic is lost.